# SAS proc sort algorithm

Tags: sorting, sas, proc

I googled, but I didn't find information about what algorithm is behind the scenes in the `proc sort` in SAS? In Python, for example, `sort()` uses [timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) .

Comment: Unfortunately, the algorithm is closed source and proprietary. You can always try asking SAS technical support this question and see if they can give you at least some information about what it's doing! They're usually pretty cool about delving into certain details for curious minds. I've learned some interesting things about the inner workings of random procedures over the years just by needing to troubleshoot them and email tech support.

Comment: Just a note to myself: The [official SAS documentation on proc sort](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/65145/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1nd17xr6wof4sn19zkmid81p926.htm) does not mention any algorithm, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

As Stu has observed, proc sort is closed source, so the best we can do is speculate. Having said that, rather than there being just one algorithm used in all situations, I suspect that the choice of sorting algorithm(s) depends on at least the following factors:

- The platform on which SAS is running
- The libname engines through which the source and destination datasets are managed.
- The settings used in the `proc sort` statement - in particular, `noequals` (which requests a slightly faster but unstable sort), `tagsort` and `threads`.
- The amount of memory available for the sort as defined via the `sortsize` and `memsize` system options.
- The size of the input dataset
- Whether any third-party sorting engines (e.g. [SyncSort](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/chsortfstart.htm#a002212805)) are being called, rather than the SAS default ones, via the `sortpgm`, `sortcutp` and other associated system options.

It is worth noting that SAS has been around through many generations of computer hardware, and the optimal choice of sorting algorithm is heavily dependent on the hardware. Even bubble sort can theoretically be optimal on old enough systems. I would very much expect SAS to account for this sort of thing.